# regex in Vietnamese characters

Tags: php, regex, unicode, diacritics

I have one string and want remove any character not in any case below:

- not in this list : ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂ
  ưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ
- not in  [a-z 0-9 A-Z]
- not is  : _ and white space.

can anyone help me with this regex in php?

Comment: You should not be using regular expressions for this. Use a unicode module to validate characters for your localized character set.

Answer (score 13):

Try this regular expression:

```
/[^a-z0-9A-Z_ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễếệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ]/u
```

The [*u* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) makes PHP to interpret the pattern string as UTF-8.

If that doesn’t work, try using [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode) like `\p{L}` for letters or the [escape sequence](http://php.net/regexp.reference.escape) `\x{1234}` for describing single Unicode characters or custom character ranges:

```
/[^a-z0-9A-Z_\x{00C0}-\x{00FF}\x{1EA0}-\x{1EFF}]/u
```

Answer (score 10):

The above regexes lacks of `ế`, also `ă` and `ề` are duplicated.
List of correct Vietnamese characters:
`àáãạảăắằẳẵặâấầẩẫậèéẹẻẽêềếểễệđìíĩỉịòóõọỏôốồổỗộơớờởỡợùúũụủưứừửữựỳỵỷỹýÀÁÃẠẢĂẮẰẲẴẶÂẤẦẨẪẬÈÉẸẺẼÊỀẾỂỄỆĐÌÍĨỈỊÒÓÕỌỎÔỐỒỔỖỘƠỚỜỞỠỢÙÚŨỤỦƯỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸÝ`
Also, remember to normalize the string in NFC form (`string.normalize('NFC')`) before testing it with the regex. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).

Comment: great catch, and good mention about normalization. The above regex from the initial answer has been updated to include these characters.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful. Vietnamese Unicode characters may be "decomposed" into "[combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)" with one codepoint for the base character and one or more codepoints for addittional diacritics, or they may be "[precomposed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character)" into single Unicode codepoints. Combining diacritics won't work as expected with a regular expression range `[]` since you will match them no matter what base character they combine with.

Older versions of Unicode did not contain the full set of Vietnamese precomposed characters so expect to find Vietnamese with combining characters in the wild. You can convert combining characters into precomposed characters using [Unicode normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) form C, **NFC**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newtext = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9A-Z_[:space:]ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂ ưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ]/u','',$text);
```

Comment: the [:space:] is a character class for whitespace: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

Comment: Your regex is missing 'ế'

Answer (score 1):

You can try, this is passed "ê,ế,Ê,Ế" with this following regex: `^[a-zA-Z_ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊẾÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêếìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ\ ]+$`

Comment: this is the most correct answer, it doesn't get the error "ê,ế,Ê,Ế,...". Vietnamese standard

Answer (score 0):

with Js you can add this

```
const regex = /^[^\u00C0-\u1EF9]+$/i;

regex.test("Việt") -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use unicode character, https://vietunicode.sourceforge.net/charset/

```
return value.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s\u00C0-\u1EF9]/g, "");
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I re-order special Vietnamese Characters by sequence A_Z, six tones, uppercase, and lowercase:

```
ÁÀẢÃẠáàảãạÂẤẦẨẪẬâấầẩẫậĂẮẰẲẴẶăắằẳẵặĐđÉÈẺẼẸéèẻẽẹÊẾỀỂỄỆêếềểễệÓÒỎÕỌóòỏõọÔỐỒỔỖỘôốồổỗộƠỚỜỞỠỢơớờởỡợÍÌỈĨỊíìỉĩịÚÙỦŨỤúùủũụƯỨỪỬỮỰưứừửữựÝỲỶỸỴýỳỷỹỵ
```

And the regex:

```
/[^a-z0-9A-Z_ÀÁÂÃÈÉÊẾÌÍÒÓÔÕÙÚĂĐĨŨƠàáâãèéêếìíòóôõùúăđĩũơƯĂẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼỀỂưăạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽềểỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừỬỮỰỲỴÝỶỸửữựỳỵỷỹ]/u
```