# How to Rewrite URL VietNamese Character IIS Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I want to Rewrite URL with Vietnam Character

```
<rule name="Detail Product">
    <match url="^Product-Detail/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page={R:0}&amp;id={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

## Finally:

> localhost/Product-Detail/con-ga-ha-ha-5.html **working**
>
> localhost/Product-Detail/con-gà-há-há-5.html **Not Working**

Comment: I don't know `regular expressions`, I always have to [search on the web](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819837/815938) when I need to use one.

Comment: Your regex only matches a-zA-Z0-9_-. Therefore just try to add the special Vietnamese characters to this list.